# Scroll View don't work with more elements in page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to make a app where I list my games (for educational purposes), but I'm with a problem in the ScrollView. They just don't scroll all the content. I found that if I remove the input and button all work nice.

My code: (I removed the function to minimize the code. The function just get data from a API and store in the apps array)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Image, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, StatusBar, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native'

export default function App() {
  const [id, setId] = React.useState('');
  const [apps, setApps] = React.useState([]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{padding: 20, flex: 1}}>
      <StatusBar hidden={false} backgroundColor={"white"} barStyle={'dark-content'} />
      <View>  
        <TextInput style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }} onChangeText={text => setId(text)} keyboardType={'numeric'} value={id} placeholder={"Insira o ID do jogo aqui"} />
        <Button onPress={e => addApp()} title="Adicionar" color="#841584" accessibilityLabel="Salvar Id" />

        <ScrollView style={{marginTop: 32}}>
          {apps.map((item, key) => (
            <View key={key} style={{alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 32}}>
              <Image style={{width: "100%", height: 200}} source={{ uri: item.image}} />
              <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Here are two screenshots, one with the input and other without

Screenshot with input:

[image: Screenshot with input]

Screenshot without input:

[image: Screenshot without input]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tough to test this out specifically without an expo snack or something, however I would try wrapping your Scrollable section with a `<View style={{flex: 1}}>`. I'm imagining the problem is because its not got a height bound parent.

If they aren't told to fit to the space they tend to just expand out thus unscrollable, if you view the [ScrollView docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview) the first section mentions:

> Keep in mind that ScrollViews must have a bounded height in order to work, since they contain unbounded-height children into a bounded container (via a scroll interaction)

Comment: This is the awnser, I have tryed to put flex:1 but in the wrong <View> I've tryed to put in the <view> after the <ScrollView> but I need to put in the <View> after the <StatusBar>. Thanks

Comment: @ToMatt np, glad to help :)